# What is the command line parameter for my app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I made my first spring boot application which is working well and I want to deploy it to my VPS server yet there is a problem. I cant run it on command line interface it works fine when I double click.

Commands I have tried so far:

> java -jar jarfilename.jar

> mvn spring-boot:run

> mvnw spring boot:run

non of them worked I would gladly add maven dependency to my pom.xlm but I right now I just want to know how I can learn what command is given when i double click.

both mvn and java commands are defined in path btw

POM file ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>name</groupId>
<artifactId>test1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>test1</name>
<description>My personal webpage</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I think the first command you try is the one you need. Maven is used for build and developing. It's just you may need to add a proper class path with _-cp_ option, or build a jar with full dependencies, so you don't need a class path.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: main/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Answer (score 2):

You should learn the about the process of development of spring boot applications - it will help a lot:

Maven is a build tool that is used to create an application’s jar (a.k.a. Artifact) from your source files. Maven compiles your sources, runs tests you have them, packages the artifact in the `target` folder which should be created after you run `mvn package` command.

After that, if the definitions in `pom.xml` are correct, you will be able to run the following:

```
cd target

java -jar my-app.jar
```

- Here `my-app.jar` is a name of the artifact that you can find a `target` folder.

Note that specifically for spring boot applications you should use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` defined in the `pom.xml` which looks like you’ve done correctly

Comment: as you can see I have spring-boot-maven-plugin under build>plugins>plugin

Answer (score 1):

So, you are running java 14 bytecode with java8

I think when you double click, system finds appropriate JVM based on the bytecode version.. where when you run from command line, first JVM from path is taken.

Use properties mentioned here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html#

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Comment: but what is the command that make this application run when I double click? I dont want to lower the version every time I see this problem.

Comment: can you run `java -version` on your machine?

Comment: Yes I can run java -version it says "java version 1.8.0_261" but I can run java 14 in IDE is that a configuration error?

Comment: so whenever you run from command line, it will be running with java8. you can do a quick dirty experiment, instead of running via mave, what you can do is, you can use `java -jar filename.jar` command and check the output.. it should be picking up java8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take it to vps, the best option is either using JAR or war.

Using it with source is obviously not a good way to run on the server.

For creating jar, you can use `package` target in maven.

for that run `mvn package` command in the project-root directory.

It will generate the log like below

[image]

Look for `Building jar:` and copy the jar to VPS.

then run `java -jar jarfilename.jar`

**BTW, do you have java 14 on your machine? I think thats the root cause why your build isnt working.**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>
```

Try changing it to older versions, and your build might start working.

Comment: Its not working on my computer where i developed it (unless I run it with double click)

Comment: What's the error you get? Can you please give the logs?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: main/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: It works when I lower it to java 8 but what I want to know is why is it working when I double click without lowering version

Comment: So, you are running java 14 bytecode with java8

I think when you double click, system finds appropriate JVM based on the bytecode version.. where when you run from command line, first JVM from path is taken.